# SQL Server database on Azure UNIQUE KEY constraint crash

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

After launching promo campaign of our software yesterday we've met some strange problems with our SQL Server database. This error occurs when users did signup for an account at our website. When it was low user traffic everything seemed to be ok and worked properly but once traffic increased to ~10 signups at a time everything goes down. Once it get down each following request to database threw an error. The only way to fix it was restarting website (until the next crash and so on).

This is the error:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint ‘AK_Users_Username’. Cannot insert duplicate key in object ‘dbo.Users’. The duplicate key value is (username). The statement has been terminated.

(Even though we check the username before adding it)

Also some another error occurred:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

This is a piece of code which adds `User` and its `License` to database:

```
var db = new CBEntities();

var user = db.Users.Add(new User
        {
            Username = model.Username,
            Firstname = model.FirstName,
            Lastname = model.LastName,
            Email = model.Email,
            Password = model.Password,
            EmailConfirmed = 0,
            Country = model.Country,
            EmailSubscribed = model.Newsletter != null && model.Newsletter.Value ? 1 : 0,
            Role = "User",
            SignUpDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        });

db.SaveChanges();

//create a initial trial license for user
var lic = db.Licenses.Add(new License
        {
            ExpirationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(21),
            UserID = user.ID,
            Key = "",
            PackageID = coupon.ID,
            Status = (int)LicenseStatus.Active,
            Type = (int)LicenseTypes.TRIAL
        });

db.SaveChanges();
user.LicenseID = lic.ID;

db.SaveChanges();
```

Site and database are running on Azure hosting. We did scale a website to STANDARD plan and it was using even several instances with 2 cores and 3.5 Gb memory. It didn't solve the error. Database currently has STANDARD service tier with S2 perf. level. (It's linked to website)..

When there are no high users traffic everything works ok!

Please help us find a solution

Comment: the first message is clear. You are trying to add the same value in username column of dbo.Users. When you say you check the username before inserting it, what exactly do you do? Is that excactly your code or a simplified version? The second message hasn't to do with the number of connections rather with the fact that something is trying to use a connection while something else is already using it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do your users login using their email address or their username?

Comment: In your code, I didn't see where you check existing usernames?

Comment: @ughai Existing usernames are checked before calling the code piece above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is structured like this.

1. Check For Duplicate Username
2. Add a User
3. Save the User to database
4. Add a License
5. Save the License to database
6. Associate the License with the user

Here each action like create user, create license and associate license are individually atomic actions. What you should have is that all these actions together should be considered atomic. I would strongly recommend to have a transaction boundary to consider user creation, license creation and its association one single atomic unit rather than treating them separately.

Regarding the unique key error

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint ‘AK_Users_Username’. Cannot insert duplicate key in object ‘dbo.Users’. The duplicate key value is (username). The statement has been terminated.

In the above sequence, there can be 2 different connections which check for the same username say 'abc.def' and try to create a user. However only one of these requests will be able to create a new user record in the database.

The second record will fail with the unique key constraint violation.

You can minimise such errors by doing another check for the username again just before you create your user. This will not completely remove the error but minimise such occurrences.

To completely Remove such errors

1. Start a Serializable transaction
2. Check the username again
3. Do normal processing...
4. Associate the License with the user
5. Commit the transaction

***Note**: Using Serializable scope may cause blocking as this is the most isolated scope.*

Reference Article on [Serializable](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-serializable-isolation-level)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 13):

You haven't enclosed the `DbContext` in a using statement. It should be disposed of like this:

```
using (var db = new CBEntities()) {

  var user = db.Users.Add(new User
          {
              Username = model.Username,
              Firstname = model.FirstName,
              Lastname = model.LastName,
              Email = model.Email,
              Password = model.Password,
              EmailConfirmed = 0,
              Country = model.Country,
              EmailSubscribed = model.Newsletter != null && model.Newsletter.Value ? 1 : 0,
              Role = "User",
              SignUpDate = DateTime.UtcNow
          });

  db.SaveChanges();

  //create a initial trial license for user
  var lic = db.Licenses.Add(new License
          {
              ExpirationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(21),
              UserID = user.ID,
              Key = "",
              PackageID = coupon.ID,
              Status = (int)LicenseStatus.Active,
              Type = (int)LicenseTypes.TRIAL
          });

  db.SaveChanges();
  user.LicenseID = lic.ID;

  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Disposing the `DbContext` closes the connection to the database. That would explain why not disposing the DbContext causes a too many connections error.

When you have little activity on the site, the connections time-out which explains why you don't have the error under a light load.

Comment: Thanks for answer Boris. But don't Entity framework closes the connection when in SaveChanges method? (see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738582.aspx)

Comment: No, it doesn't. What is relevant here is this line: **"If the object context creates the connection, the connection will always be disposed when the context is disposed."** That is what you do when you call `var db = new CBEntities();` It will use the existing connection when you call `db.SaveChanges();`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain me this line (I'm confused a bit): " It opens connections only when required, for example to execute a query or to call SaveChanges. Object Services then closes the connection when the operation is complete." Thanks

Comment: I'm confused about it as well. A bit of googling turned out this: http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html Turns out that you don't have to Dispose, but not doing so is unpredictable at best (article + comments are interesting),

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is to you: I've never had those kinds of errors by putting new DbContext in using statements. But then again, I've never used a DbContext without a using statement. How are things going for you?

Comment: well it's difficult to test this error because it occurs only during high user traffic but thank you Boris for your help

Comment: You should be able to unit test this by generating 11+ random usernames at the same time and putting them through this application.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this eror is still happening from time to time (like each 30-50  unique signup) and not only when user traffic is high.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the previous answers, you should always enclose your `DbContext` in using statements. Not only in this piece of code, but every time you use it.

The Unique Key constraint problem however can be caused by various other reasons.
We cannot see the code you are using for checking the already existing usernames, but I guess it is written in C#. When you insert a new line SQL Server checks the user name constraint for you. There are a lot of differences in string comparison in SQL server compared to C#.

First of all SQL Server relies on the default collation of the DB if no collation is specified on the column. The default collation of SQL Azure is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. CI means case insensitive AS means Accent Sensitive.
This means that two string values are considered equal when they only differ in the casing. So user123 is equal to USER123 and User123 and so on.

The other thing that can cause problems is the handling of trailing spaces. SQL Server compares stings basically by comparing their characters one by one. If one string is shorter than the other it adds extra spaces to the end of the shorter one to make their length equal. This way `'User123'` is equal to `'User123    '` and to any string that starts with User123 and ends with a number of spaces. This means that you should always trim the usernames before saving them.